# how to handle the log in auth key of telegram web on selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, telegram

I'm using python and selenium to automate a task on the telegram web
my task should be repeated many times so I don't want to log in every time
saving the cookies of the driver doesn't work and after some searching I found that telegram saves the auth key on the local storage but I didn't find how or where
note : I'm using chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chrom_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\robert.car\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
```

user-data-dir considers profile as default , and you don't have to specify that . If its something else specify it through profile-directory argument

```
chrom_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\robert.car\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
chrom_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 1")
```

User-dir will have all the session related information you don't have to login again